# Drag and Drop Support

Tags: notebooks, user-interface

Is there a way to effectively get drag and drop so you can drag files onto nbs in Windows?

For example similar to the way .bat scripts work.

Ideally I would like the script to automatically execute on run.

Comment: Notebooks are not meant to be treated as programs.  You might want to look into `.m` files to be used as scripts.  This also applies to your question about auto-evaluating a notebook on open, which is not such a good idea.  Notebooks are *documents*, not programs, and *should not* auto-evaluate.  It's a serious security risk.  You can write scripts instead, which are programs, and are opened/run with a different expectation.

Comment: I think the lack of votes here is because nobody clearly understands what the code does. Perhaps you could use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) to make a recording of how this drag and drop looks/works. I could see myself voting for a drag and drop functionality but I can't vote on just the words "drag and drop" when I don't know what they mean in this context.

Comment: @Picket good point.  I will post more information.  If you read the `@echo off` post hopefully you will notice it is pretty simple.  Simple save the file as .bat and drag and drop files onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works if you are simply trying to run data on the command line.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\Math" -noprompt -run "ToExpression@StringJoin@Riffle[Drop[StringSplit[UsingFrontEnd@Import[$CommandLine[[5]], \"Text\"],\"\n\",All], 4], \"\n\"];Quit[];" %0 %*
exit /b

Print[$CommandLine[[6;;]]];
Print[23];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have node.js installed this works well.

print.bat http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HSr2Dm9D

edit.bat

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" -p "require('fs').writeFileSync('./args.txt',JSON.stringify(process.argv));require('child_process').exec('C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\nb.nb',function (error, stdout, stderr) {if(error != null) {console.log('exec error: ' + error);}});" %0 %*
exit
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)

(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 10.0' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       158,          7]
NotebookDataLength[      4879,        124]
NotebookOptionsPosition[      3950,         96]
NotebookOutlinePosition[      4981,        126]
CellTagsIndexPosition[      4938,        123]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"Module", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"{", 
    RowBox[{"str", ",", "nb"}], "}"}], ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"If", "[", 
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"Length", "@", "$CommandLines"}], "<", "3"}], ",", 
          RowBox[{"Throw", "[", "1", "]"}]}], "]"}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"str", "=", 
         RowBox[{"OpenWrite", "[", 
          RowBox[{"$TemporaryDirectory", "<>", "\"\<\\\\\>\"", "<>", 
           RowBox[{"Last", "@", 
            RowBox[{"StringSplit", "[", 
             RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"$CommandLines", "[", 
               RowBox[{"[", "3", "]"}], "]"}], ",", "\"\<\\\\\>\""}], "]"}]}], 
           "<>", "\"\<.nb\>\""}], "]"}]}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"WriteString", "[", 
         RowBox[{"str", ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
          RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
           RowBox[{
            RowBox[{"Import", "[", 
             RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"$CommandLines", "[", 
               RowBox[{"[", "3", "]"}], "]"}], ",", "\"\<Text\>\""}], "]"}], ",", 
            "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
            RowBox[{
            "\"\<@echo off\n\\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\\\" -p \
    \\\"require('fs').writeFileSync('./args.txt',JSON.stringify(process.argv));\
    require('child_process').exec('C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\\
    nb.nb',function (error, stdout, stderr) {if(error != null) {console.log('exec \
    error: ' + error);}});\\\" %0 %*\nexit\n\>\"", "\[Rule]", "\"\<\>\""}]}], 
           "]"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", "]"}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"NotebookClose", "[", 
         RowBox[{"EvaluationNotebook", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";", 
        "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"nb", " ", "=", 
         RowBox[{"NotebookOpen", "[", 
          RowBox[{"Close", "[", "str", "]"}], "]"}]}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"SetOptions", "[", 
         RowBox[{"nb", ",", 
          RowBox[{"NotebookEventActions", "\[Rule]", 
           RowBox[{"{", 
            RowBox[{
             RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"{", 
               RowBox[{"\"\<MenuCommand\>\"", ",", "\"\<Save\>\""}], "}"}], 
              "\[RuleDelayed]", 
              RowBox[{"(", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
               RowBox[{
                RowBox[{"NotebookSave", "[", 
                 RowBox[{"InputNotebook", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";", 
                "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
                RowBox[{"Export", "[", 
                 RowBox[{
                  RowBox[{"$CommandLines", "[", 
                   RowBox[{"[", "3", "]"}], "]"}], ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
                  RowBox[{
                  "\"\<@echo off\n\\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\\\
    \" -p \\\"require('fs').writeFileSync('./args.txt',JSON.stringify(process.\
    argv));require('child_process').exec('C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\Desktop\
    \\\\\\\\nb.nb',function (error, stdout, stderr) {if(error != null) \
    {console.log('exec error: ' + error);}});\\\" %0 %*\nexit\n\>\"", " ", "<>", 
                   "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
                   RowBox[{"Import", "[", 
                    RowBox[{
                     RowBox[{"NotebookFileName", "[", 
                      RowBox[{"InputNotebook", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ",", 
                     "\"\<Text\>\""}], "]"}]}], ",", "\"\<Text\>\""}], "]"}], 
                ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", ")"}]}], ",", 
             RowBox[{"PassEventsDown", "\[Rule]", "False"}]}], "}"}]}]}], "]"}], 
        ";"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", "]"}]], "Input"]
    },
    InitializationCellEvaluation->True,
    InitializationCellWarning->False,
    NotebookEventActions->{{"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> (NotebookSave[
         InputNotebook[]]; Export[
         Part[$CellContext`$CommandLines, 3], 
     StringJoin[
     "@echo off\n\"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe\" -p \
\"require('fs').writeFileSync('./args.txt',JSON.stringify(process.argv));\
require('child_process').exec('C:\\\\Users\\\\a\\\\Desktop\\\\nb.nb',function \
(error, stdout, stderr) {if(error != null) {console.log('exec error: ' + \
error);}});\" %0 %*\nexit\n", 
      Import[
       NotebookFileName[
        InputNotebook[]], "Text"]], "Text"]; Null), PassEventsDown -> False},
WindowSize->{667, 670},
WindowMargins->{{Automatic, 0}, {Automatic, 0}},
InitializationCell->True,
FrontEndVersion->"10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 1, 2014)",
StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"
]
(* End of Notebook Content *)

(* Internal cache information *)
(*CellTagsOutline
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*CellTagsIndex
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*NotebookFileOutline
Notebook[{
Cell[558, 20, 3388, 74, 712, "Input"]
}
]
*)

(* End of internal cache information *)
```

Desktop/nb.nb

```
(* Content-type: application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica *)

(*** Wolfram Notebook File ***)
(* http://www.wolfram.com/nb *)

(* CreatedBy='Mathematica 10.0' *)

(*CacheID: 234*)
(* Internal cache information:
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookFileLineBreakTest
NotebookDataPosition[       158,          7]
NotebookDataLength[      2733,         79]
NotebookOptionsPosition[      2400,         63]
NotebookOutlinePosition[      2835,         81]
CellTagsIndexPosition[      2792,         78]
WindowFrame->Normal*)

(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"$CommandLines", " ", "=", 
       RowBox[{"Import", "[", 
        RowBox[{
        "\"\<C:\\\\Users\\\\a\\\\Desktop\\\\args.txt\>\"", ",", "\"\<JSON\>\""}], 
        "]"}]}], ";"}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
     RowBox[{"Module", "[", 
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{"{", "str", "}"}], ",", 
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{"str", " ", "=", " ", 
         RowBox[{"OpenWrite", "[", 
          RowBox[{"$TemporaryDirectory", "<>", "\"\<\\\\\>\"", "<>", 
           RowBox[{"Last", "@", 
            RowBox[{"StringSplit", "[", 
             RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"$CommandLines", "[", 
               RowBox[{"[", "2", "]"}], "]"}], ",", "\"\<\\\\\>\""}], "]"}]}], 
           "<>", "\"\<.nb\>\""}], " ", "]"}]}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{"WriteString", "[", 
         RowBox[{"str", ",", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
          RowBox[{"StringReplace", "[", 
           RowBox[{
            RowBox[{"Import", "[", 
             RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"$CommandLines", "[", 
           RowBox[{"[", "2", "]"}], "]"}], ",", "\"\<Text\>\""}], "]"}], ",", 
        "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
        RowBox[{
        "\"\<@echo off\n\\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\nodejs\\\\node.exe\\\" -p \
\\\"require('fs').writeFileSync('./args.txt',JSON.stringify(process.argv));\
require('child_process').exec('C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\a\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\\
nb.nb',function (error, stdout, stderr) {if(error != null) {console.log('exec \
error: ' + error);}});\\\" %0 %*\nexit\n\>\"", "\[Rule]", "\"\<\>\""}]}], 
       "]"}]}], "\[IndentingNewLine]", "\[IndentingNewLine]", "]"}], ";", 
    "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
    RowBox[{"SystemOpen", "[", 
     RowBox[{"Close", "[", "str", "]"}], "]"}], ";", "\[IndentingNewLine]", 
    RowBox[{"NotebookClose", "[", 
     RowBox[{"EvaluationNotebook", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";"}]}], 
  "\[IndentingNewLine]", "]"}]}], "Input"]
},
InitializationCellEvaluation->True,
InitializationCellWarning->False,
WindowSize->{667, 670},
WindowMargins->{{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}},
InitializationCell->True,
FrontEndVersion->"10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 1, 2014)",
StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"
]
(* End of Notebook Content *)

(* Internal cache information *)
(*CellTagsOutline
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*CellTagsIndex
CellTagsIndex->{}
*)
(*NotebookFileOutline
Notebook[{
Cell[558, 20, 1838, 41, 432, "Input"]
}
]
*)

(* End of internal cache information *)
```

Answer (score 0):

test.m don't remember what this is used for.

```
in:=(ToExpression@InputString[]);
If[Length@$CommandLine<5,
  Print["no args"],
  Print@ToExpression@$CommandLine[[5]]
]
```

Evaluate Notebook.

```
nb = Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ToExpression@ToString[Hold[
           nb2 = CreateDocument[{
              TextCell["The head", "Section"],
              TextCell["first cell"],
              Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Print", "[", "23", "]"}]], "Input"]
              }];
           NotebookEvaluate[nb2, InsertResults -> True];
           NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]];
           ], InputForm]][[1, 3]]], "Input", 
     InitializationCell -> True]}, 
   InitializationCellEvaluation -> False, 
   InitializationCellWarning -> False];
UsingFrontEnd@Export["C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\nb.nb", nb];
Run["C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\nb.nb"];
```